# Tikz node won't apply left (nor right) alignment

Tags: latex, tikz

I have been struggling with this issue for a while. I want to insert a title on a white box on top of a background image for a report cover, and everything is coming up great with the exception of the title alignment. It is centered and I want to make it left aligned, but so far none of the options I have tried have worked.

So far, this is what I got:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{titlepage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
     \node at (current page.center)      {\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-10x16}};
     \node[fill=white, scale=2, text=red, text width=94mm, align=left] at ([xshift=7mm,yshift=30mm]current page.center) {\makecell{\textbf{The title goes here and it is very}\\\textbf{long so it covers two lines}\\\Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}\\[-18pt]\scalebox{.35}{\textbf{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont DEPARTMENT OF SOME ENGINEERING DISCIPLINE $\vert$ MY UNIVERSITY}}\\[-7pt]\scalebox{.35}{\textbf{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont MY NAME HERE $\vert$ NAME OF PROGRAM}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{titlepage}
```

I have tried raggedright options with the `\usepackage{ragged2e}` and the `\begin{flushleft}\end{flushleft}` approach with different variations but I don't seem to make it align to the left or even to the right.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid all this messing with `\makecell` and whatnot. Instead use a simple minipage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node at (current page.center)      {\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-10x16}};
  \node[
    fill=white, 
    text=red, 
    text width=92mm, 
    font=\bfseries
  ] at ([yshift=30mm]current page.center) {
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
      \LARGE The title goes here and it is very
      
      long so it covers two lines
      
      \vskip-0.5cm
          
      \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
      
      \vskip0.1cm
      
      \scriptsize\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont DEPARTMENT OF SOME ENGINEERING DISCIPLINE $\vert$ MY UNIVERSITY
      
      NAME HERE $\vert$ NAME OF PROGRAM
      
    \end{minipage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```